# Program error can't decide between Argument and State exception?

Tags: java, exception

I'm a little new to the whole exception-business, so throwing exceptions is scary stuff.
Now, I've got a method that "can't decide" what is the right exception to throw. I'm currently working on an assignment, and can't find out what's wrong.

```
public void setEmail(String email) {
    if (email.contains("@flowerland.com")) {
        String[] tempEmail = email.split("@");
        String tempName = tempEmail[0];
        String name = tempName.substring(0, tempName.indexOf('.'));
        String surname = tempName.substring(tempName.indexOf('.')+1, tempName.length());
        String Name = name + " " + surname;
        if (Name.equalsIgnoreCase(this.name)) {
            this.email = name + "." + surname + "@flowerland.com";
        }
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("E-mail does not match name.");
    }
}
```

Please excuse the variable-names, I've altered them 'cause they originally weren't in English, so they're a little sloppy.

The point of this method is to check a string (an email-address) and see if it's equal to the current object's name.
The problem is that when I run the "test"-code, it'll tell me that "IllegalStateException" is expected if IllegalArgumentException is in the code, and vice versa.
This is very frustrating, and I was hoping to get some light shed on all of this.

Comment: I think you need to take that up with whoever wrote the testcase, to understand under which conditions they expect which of these exceptions. Generally, Illegal Argument is thrown when the parameters are inherently unreasonable, and Illegal State is thrown when the action doesn't make sense given the current values of the object's fields (or those of objects it refers to). It sounds like the test is trying to draw that distinction... and the fact that you have no `else` for your second `if` looks suspicious to me.

Comment: The last sentence of your comment sparked an idea. I got the method to work, though I had to add 3 more if-else statements. It's a real mess, but it works... I guess.